# 403.14 - Publishing Asp.Net Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

I'm trying publish an Asp.Net Core to an IIS 8 Server.

Here is my StartUp class

[image]

First, I read [this tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) and then, proceed with deploy.

This is the schema of my iis, and the app that I'm trying deploy is that one named "cola".

[image]

and this is the configuration of Asp.net Core pool

[image]

When I run the app, I get this error.

[image]

**UPDATE - 05/05/16**

If I go in homolog > cola > "Directory Browsing" and enable it, I have this result, but it's wrong cause I need to be redirected to Home/Index action.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: have you turned on the necessary .Net framework/IIS features from the control panel "Turn Windows Features On Or Off"

Comment: Did you check permission to wwwroot folder and Directory browsing? Here is useful link for directory browsing https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/directorybrowse

Comment: Yes, all features of IIS that are asked in the asp.net core tutorial are turned on. And, if I turn on directory permission, then the app.

Comment: try to add your app outside of "Default Web Site" and assign port number different then default one (80), for example 8080

Comment: it's already outside of default web app. And runs at port 8585... =/

Comment: open the web.config and change the 'stdoutLogEnabled' setting to true.  restart your webpage and see if an error log is written out to ..\logs\stdout.log

Comment: you can also try run web.cmd in your approot folder directly.  If you do that, does it start correctly?  If that starts up correctly, can you browse to your app on port 5000 (default port for the web.cmd script)?

Comment: So, I did run my web.cmd and the app run correctly. But, restarting my web site and changing my web.config dores not generate any log at my logs path...

Comment: I'm having the same issue... if I add an index.html it shows up, but it seems as if MVC routes are not being processed.  Works fine under IIS express, when I host it under IIS I get a 403.14, it can't create the logfile even though my app pool is mapped to an admin user on the box for testing.  Very frustrating.

Comment: I too have this problem. Any luck solving it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with core 1.1
The reason was that in my published output was missed web.config file
Try add it manually

Answer (score 0):

With my ASP.NET Core 2.0 site, my web.config was also missing.  Once added, the 403.14 went away.  I'm still having some issues, but that was my solution to this particular error.

My understanding is the web.config is only used on the server for IIS settings but it still seems strange there is little to no mention of this in the deployment documentation.

Comment: Just to confirm, this was, in fact, the issue and I now have a deployed and functioning site.

Answer (score 0):

the physical path is not \wwwroot but one level higher